# iOS system settings with time picker UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, appsettings, settings.bundle

I need to add time picker to system settings for my app, Is it possible? I see there is a UITextField but no property with time picker for the UITextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `UIPickerView` for showing picker
`UITextFieldDelegates` for textfield start editing

On click on textfield

- Disable Keyboard
- Show picker
- On picker delegate set the textfield with selected value

Edit : In case of settings page which is managed with  a plist.It is impossible to do so since apple doesnt give such wide support on the setings page.You van add settings to the application itself as a setting page and do all this

Comment: Thanks, I know how to add picker for textfield in app. But I need this picker in iPhone system settings for My application

Comment: system setting means the application setting page  in the iphone settings?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I need it to setup start time setting for my app.

Comment: @Romula Edited my answer.It is not possible

Answer (score -1):

Initialize a textfield. for example UITextField *txtFld;

```
//Text Field delegate method
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:FRAME];
     datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
     [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeTextFieldValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
     [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
}

-(void)changeTextFieldValue:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *date = [datePicker date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date ];
    txtFld.text = dateString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, check pls above comments

Comment: You cant access the settings. So this is impossible